# JavaScript Recursive function return undefined instead of an array

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

I have the next function:

```
function solveSudoku(prev_tab, fila, columna) {

  let tab = _.cloneDeep(prev_tab);
  let sig_fila = fila;
  let sig_col = columna;

  if (fila === 8 && columna === 8) {
    //console.log(tab);
    return tab;
  }

  if (columna === 8) {
    sig_col = 0;
    sig_fila = sig_fila + 1
  } else {
    sig_col = sig_col + 1;
  }

  if ((tab[fila][columna]) !== '') {
    solveSudoku(tab, sig_fila, sig_col)
  } else {
    for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
      if (numeroValido(tab, num, fila, columna)) {
        tab[fila][columna] = num;
        //tab.toString();
        solveSudoku(tab, sig_fila, sig_col)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it returns undefined instead of a 2D array, i already try to add return in every recursive call =>

```
return solveSudoku( tab, sig_fila, sig_col )
```

but now that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with algorithms for solving sudoku, so I don't know if the algorithm below is correct.

But you need to ensure that the result of the recursion is returned. In my update below, I return the first recursive call. In the loop, I only return it if the recursion successfully found a solution, otherwise the loop continues trying other numbers in the column.

```js
function solveSudoku(prev_tab, fila, columna) {

  let tab = _.cloneDeep(prev_tab);
  let sig_fila = fila;
  let sig_col = columna;

  if (fila === 8 && columna === 8) {
    //console.log(tab);
    return tab;
  }

  if (columna === 8) {
    sig_col = 0;
    sig_fila = sig_fila + 1
  } else {
    sig_col = sig_col + 1;
  }

  if ((tab[fila][columna]) !== '') {
    return solveSudoku(tab, sig_fila, sig_col)
  } else {
    for (let num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
      if (numeroValido(tab, num, fila, columna)) {
        tab[fila][columna] = num;
        //tab.toString();
        let result = solveSudoku(tab, sig_fila, sig_col);
        if (result) { // continue searching if the recursion failed
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```